# Word Automation - Disable Alerts

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am automating Word, so I would like to suppress all alerts.

```
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
word.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

I use the code listed above, but I keep getting messages from Word - e.g., the document is already open. Is there a way to avoid this? How to supress all those stupid messageboxes?

**EDIT**:
Concider to all answers, I guess a watchdog is really the only option. To bad nothing has changed in last years.

Thread can be closed without a real answer.

Comment: My first question is why is your code trying to open a document that's already open?

Comment: Can you post complete code so that the message can be reproduced?

Comment: Word.Document wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(document); can produce this behavior. The question is not how to avoid such errors, because it can not be done in every case (user interaction e.g.).

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Your users are opening documents *while* your macro is running? Either way, unless you're experiencing some pretty epic race conditions in MS Word, a guard clause at the beginning of whatever method it is that tries to open a document will work just fine.

Comment: Exactly. A user could start Word while the automation is running, this could lead the automation to failure. Since those messageboxes are blocking the process execution, i would wait forever to perform the next opperation. I could implement a timeout guard, but this is not the most gracefull way - from my point of view. Further there are non user related issues, like filling format fields that might result in a messagebox aswell...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The portion of code that you have posted obviously looks correct, but there isn't enough for me to reproduce the behavior that you describe. However...

**I have a strong suspicion the answer is that you can't completely suppress messages in Word.** It was designed as a user-interactive application, and the `DisplayAlerts` setting is a bit of a hit-or-miss proposition. Certain errors look like they might be exempted from the specified alert setting and be displayed anyway. For example, I've seen spelling and grammar errors behave like this before.

**The best thing to do is try to anticipate the errors that may occur and avoid generating them.** In your case, you should be checking to see if the document you're about to open is already open. I'm not sure why you'd ever be generating this error in the first place (are you catching the error and *then* searching for the existing instance of the document to operate on it, or how does your code continue running?), but it should be fairly straightforward to insert a few guard clauses before you start executing the relevant code.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion the answer is that you can't completely suppress messages in Word. -> This statement is correct. You can never suppress all messages in Word.

Comment: Cody gray is right. You'll find that there are +plenty+ of messages that can still pop when you least expect it. You'll want plenty of logging, and possibly even a watchdog class that essentially will hardkill the instance of Word you started if it doesn't come back within some reasonable amount of time. Otherwise, if you're running unattended you're very likely to eventually hang word and thus your app. It's not optimal but plenty of people have gotten word working in this manner.

Comment: I still think a simple check before every method that could *possibly* (determined through extensive testing and user feedback) generate an exceptional condition (i.e., error message) would head off 99.9% of your troubles with the least amount of expended effort and trouble. Like (pseudo-code): `If thisFile.IsAlreadyOpen Then Exit Sub`

Comment: An open file is just one of several conditions, that will cause a failure. I guess a watchdog is really the only option. To bad nothing has changed in last years.

Comment: @Jaster: Automation is really more of a bonus than a true "feature" of Word. As I mentioned above, it's primarily designed to be user-interactive, and I wouldn't have too much expectation that this ever be "fixed." I'm sorry that you can't find an ideal solution.

Comment: I disagree with you. Office automation is a feature and it used to be way more "technical" than it become today. With all those pointless security discussions, which forced microsoft to implement those ridicilous limitations.