# Trying to print a MS Word document with VB.NET console application, but stopped by macro dialog

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to print a MS Word document, but for documents that contain macros I am being stopped by a warning message "The macros in this project are disabled."

I already am trying to disable this message using DisabledAutoMacros and AutomationSecurity.

Is there any way to avoid this dialog, or sense it and click ok, or set a timeout to kill the process if I cannot get by it?

```
Imports word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
        Dim path = args(1)
        Dim printer = args(2)
        Dim wordApp As word.Application = New word.Application
        wordApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros(1)
        wordApp.AutomationSecurity = 3
        wordApp.Visible = False
        Dim doc As word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open(path)
        wordApp.ActivePrinter = printer
        Dim background As Object = False
        doc.PrintOut(background)
        doc.Close(False)
        wordApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros(0)
        wordApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

[image]

Comment: No idea if it will help, but you could try the code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245395/word-automation-disable-alerts) - i.e. `wordApp.DisplayAlerts = word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone`.

Comment: I tried wordApp.DisplayAlerts = word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone.  However it not not help.

Comment: Are your documents in binary (.doc) or Open XML (.docm/.docx) format?

Comment: Both .doc and .docx need to be supported.